# Let A be an infinite set, and S a sequence that contains A. Is A countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Let $ A $ be an infinite set, and $ S $ a sequence that every element of $ A $ appears at least one time. How can I prove that $ A $ is countable (or uncountable)?

Comment: A is countable, just by the definition of countability. Countable means there exists a mapping from the set to the set of integers, which just means that, you can create a sequence that contains all the elements of the set atleast once!

Comment: Note that there's a slight subtlety here - some authors use "countable" to mean "countable *and infinite*." Of course, in this example $A$ might well be finite, so we have to be a bit careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map $A\to\Bbb N$ by mapping $a\in A$ to the minimal index in the sequence where $a$ occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is:
Let a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to a set A. Go to prove that $f$ is a surjection. Then you can get A is countable.

By the way I'm also a current student in discrete math. ;)